# Scrolling a large Image in HTML - PhoneGap - Windows phone 8

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a large image that i want the user to scroll, when i add the image normally in an img tag it scrolls up and down normally but it don't scroll right or left.

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="someimage" alt="map" width="1980" height="889">
</div>
```

This code work on windows phone 8 by scrolling up and down but not left and right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, that's not a background image. That's just an image.

Comment: I know, i meant functionality wise, my bad fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow:scroll;
```

in the css of the div